# Post your page in facebook

Tags: php, facebook

When we copy link of a page to share in facebook, I see that the post is properly displayed with the image and some details.  I've read of how to auto post on facebook through php.  But what if other user will just copy my link and post to their facebook status, how can I make sure it will be displayed properly with image and details?  Sorry but I'm not sure what this is called.  Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean

Comment: For example, when i visit a news page and i want to share it in my facebook status, I copy the link and paste it in the status area... then facebook displays it with a image with a title and some description... is it automatic? or do i have to make some coding on my side so it will appear that way?

Comment: Hello. Do you have any example code you made so far?